# Как создать сервер для работы с сокетами?

Tags: php, apache, yii2, websocket

Знакомлюсь с сокетами на локальном сервере . Сервер , по которому клиент подключается с сервером запускаю через консоль . Все отлично работает . Вот пришла пора выложить сайт в сеть , на хостинг . И сразу появляется вопрос : а как же запускать этот сервер теперь , на реальном хостинге ? не через консоль ведь точно

Comment: а можете добавить материал по сокетам я тоже очень упорно знакомлюсь. Как и что подключали? я уже до node.js  знакомилс от сюда https://github.com/morozovsk/websocket вот по этой статье https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/ даже нашел пару push сервисов. Надо могу поделится своими знаниями.

Comment: пишу на php . Использую библиотеку Ratchet и  ZMQ . Да з сокетами я в целом разобрался , но вот только з размещением сайта на хостинг не все так просто оказывается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А чем Вас смущает консоль? Консоль является главным элементом передачи команд от пользователя к программному обеспечению. Запускайте через консоль.

Запускать подобное творение минимум нужно на VPS, т.к на обычным хостинге вы его не запустите, обычно хостинг провайдеры запрещают использовать привязку к локальным портам.

Единственное, желательно поставить какой-нибудь supervisord, чтобы контролировать сам демон и выполнять определенные действия, если он падает.